# Auth::check() returns false in BaseController when I'm logged in?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access `Auth::user()->id` in a base controller to log something but it is returning false when I run `Auth::check()` before it, I know for a fact I'm logged in?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Cookie;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Config;
use App\Http\Controllers\VotingController;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request) 
    {
        exit(Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should not return false! Either id or null

Comment: Try `Auth::id()`

Comment: @MahdiYounesi returns null.

Comment: Login and try again Auth::id()

Comment: Still returns null.

Comment: That's weird, It seems you never get authenticated, try with other user

Comment: It works fine inside a controller that's connected to a route, just not the base controller. I've also tried with another user and its the same.

Comment: Plz provide the  basecontroller code

Comment: I've added my BaseController class.

Answer (score 0):

Add `web` middlware to `baseController`